# How can I fetch the Number of Clicks on a YouTube LiveChat Message?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am using YouTube [LiveChat Insert API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert) to put some external website links into a user's YouTube LiveStream. The URL is inserted into the LiveChat once every 15 minutes.

Our requirement now is to get the metrics from these LiveChat messages inserted by the system into the user's LiveStream. For ex:

- Number of Views on a particular LiveChat Message
- Number of Clicks on a particular LiveChat Message
- Average engagement/views data in the LiveChat Box during the LiveStream

I have already tried using the [LiveChatMessages API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#properties) to fetch that data but to no avail. I couldn't find any API in the YouTube Data or YouTube Analytics APIs that could provide me that data.

Does it mean this data & metrics is not available on YouTube? Is there any way to get such metrics from YouTube or some other service?

Comment: Is the website you shared the URL, a website you control ?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison no, the URL inserted in the LiveChat will be of a vendor/brand which we don't have control over.

We definitely can create a URL forwarder service on our domain that can collect the clicks data. But I wish to know if it's possible in a direct manner also?

Comment: I don't know if YouTube provides such metrics but if I were you I would use as you said a URL forwarder service to collect such metrics.